# How do I add `watch' command to a shell script?

Tags: bash, function, watch

I have a script that greps and awks and counts for ip addresses with multiple http status codes.  It doesn't really matter what the script is though, because my goal is as follows:

I want to invoke the `watch' command inside this script so that it will update the display every few seconds with new data received from the dynamic apache logs.

i can call my script fine as follows:

```
$ watch --no-title ./bad_request.sh
```

But I would much rather have the `watch' command inside the script itself, to make calling the script from the command prompt much cleaner.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#identify repeated offenders through 401 and 403 status codes
  for ip in `awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/* | sort -u`; do echo -n "$ip "; awk '{print $1 " " $9}' /var/log/apache2/* | egrep "( 401| 403)"| grep -c $ip; done | sort -k2 -r
```

Now, I have tried just inserting "watch -d --no-title" inside the script, right before the for loop, but it errors out angrily.  I think it's because it is only processing until it reaches the end of the first command.  I've tried putting backticks, and $() around the entire script, as well.  I've also tried making the bulk of the script a bash function, and calling watch on the function.  No dice.

Any ideas?

By the way, I'm also open to improvements on the script - I do realize it's a bit redundant/inefficient.  Of course, that should probably be reserved for a different Stack Overflow question.

Thanks,

Kevin

EDIT:  And one more thing, I can just call `while true; do <bulk of script>; sleep 1; clear;` but I hate that.  It works, but the screen flickers, and it's just not the right way to do this.

EDIT 2:  Another nasty hack that works, is to simply create two scripts.  The first one is:

```
watch --no-title ./bad_request
```

And then just call that script.  That works fine, but there has to be a better way.

EDIT 3 (sorry...):  I took the -d flag off of `watch'.  It's not necessary for my script.

Comment: One obvious improvement on that script would be some line breaks...

Comment: yeah, sorry about that.  Im usually better about doing that, this was such a quick hack, i just copy pasted from the command line into a script and forgot to format it nicely... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heed the unix philosophy:

```
 A program should do one and only one thing and do it well.
```

Applied to your case:

```
A script should do one and only one thing and do it well.
```

Your "nasty hack" is actually a step in the right direction.

You'll never know if one day you'll need to "watch --no-title" on another script. At that point if you follow the unix philosophy you'd already have a script to do that.

You already see one complication of trying to make a script do too many things at once - quote hell.

Keep it simple.

Comment: yes, and many people smarter than I, have told me the same thing enough times, that I finally get it.  But what I don't like in this particular case, is that if I'm on a server, I have to wget two scripts, then execute them, or wget a zip package, or copy/paste, or base64 encode and decode two scripts.  I'd much rather this be one script, and keep the watch --no-title $1 as a seperate and useful script.

Comment: although, i guess i'm being dramatic here, it's not that big of a deal to untar a 2 script package onto a server and then run it.  Especially considering this script is something i would run in a screen for hours to collect the data...  Point taken.  :)

Comment: Also: shell aliases are meant for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 1):

the correct usage would be:

```
watch -d --no-title "/bin/bash for ip in `awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/* | sort -u`; do echo -n "$ip "; awk '{print $1 " " $9}' /var/log/apache2/* | egrep '( 401| 403)'| grep -c $ip; done | sort -k2 -r"
```

Comment: hmmm, i think you're on the right track here, but it still doesn't like it, probably because of the quotes within quotes... i'll keep toying with it

Comment: arghhhhh.  I still think you're on the right track here.  If I can successfully call a bash script within a script, then i should be able to call watch /bin/bash <script>.  I just can't get it to go without getting angry.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does `tail -f <file>` help?

[man tail](http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html)

Comment: no, that would really only tail the actual code of the script. There might be a way to tail -f <the_execution_of_the_script>.  Maybe stdout?  Either way, I'm going with the above, unix philosophy in this case..  keep it simple..

Comment: You're thinking of the wrong `<file>`. Log the output of the script to a file, then tail that.